# Question about a proof in integration theory

Tags: calculus, integration, proof-explanation

I have a doubt about a proof in integration theory. First let me introduce a

**Definition (antiderivative)**

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be continuous. We call an antiderivative of $f$ every function $F\in C^0([a,b])\cap C^1((a,b))$ such that $F'(x)=f(x)$.

**Theorem**

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be continuous and let $F_1$ and $F_2$ be two antiderivatives. Then $\exists \ c\in \mathbb R :F_2(x)=F_1(x)+c \ \forall x \in [a,b]$.

**Proof**

Let $G(x):=F_2(x)-F_1(x)$. Since $F_1$ and $F_2$ are both antiderivatives $G\in C^0([a,b])\cap C^1((a,b))$

$G'(x)=F'_2(x)-F'_1(x)=f(x)-f(x)=0\ \forall x \in \mathbb R$

So the derivative of $G$ equals to zero.

Here comes the doubt, after this it says: is not the fact that the derivative is zero that implies $G$ is a constant, but using Lagrange mean value theorem:

In every $[a,x_0] \subset [a,b]$ for Lagrange mean value theorem we have

$G(x_0)-G(a)=(x_0-a)G'(x_0)=0,\ c\in(a,x_0) \Rightarrow G(x_0)=G(a)\ \forall x\in(a,x_0) \Rightarrow$

$\Rightarrow G(x_0)=G(a)\ \forall x\in [a,b] \Rightarrow G(x_0)=c \Rightarrow F_2(x)=F_1(x)+c \ \forall x\in[a,b]$.

Why I'm not allowed to say that if the derivative is zero the function is a constant?

Is that because if a function is constant then the derivative is zero, and not vice versa?

Comment: Very good question! A thing is not true unless it is proven. Derivative of a constant function is zero and this is an immediate consequence of the definition. But there is no constructive definition of anti-derivative so it not possible to get the converse in obvious manner. This also shows that mean value theorem is non-trivial (on par with properties of continuous functions on closed intervals and completeness of real numbers) although it may seem obvious.

Comment: Writing $A\implies B\implies C$ when you really mean "$A$ implies $B,$ which implies $C$" is a misuse of notation that in many cases (like this) also leads to really hard-to-read formulas. It's better to use some words in cases like this. (I also cringe a bit whenever I see someone write $\forall$ as shorthand for "for all" _after_ the statement that it is quantifying.) Besides, you seem to have numerous typos (wrong letters) in that final series of equations.

Comment: If the book you're reading has already proved that $g$ is a constant function on $[a,b]$ if $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and $g'(x)=0$ for all $x\in(a,b),$ then I think it is unnecessary to invoke MVT in the proof in the question. On the other hand, "zero derivative implies constant function" is a corollary of the theorem in the question, so maybe these facts are developed that way.

Comment: @DavidK thanks for both of your comments, sorry for the errors in the notation, I'm still at my first year! Can you explain me briefly why is right to quantify before the statement? Is that because the quantities I'm considering depend from the quantification so is important to quantify before introducing them?

Comment: With the "for all" notation, it's just the way I'm used to seeing the notation defined: that is, I'm accustomed to see $\forall x.P$ meaning "$P$ for all $x.$" Wouldn't it be weird to see someone write $x^2dx\int_a^b$ instead of $\int_a^b x^2dx$? Sometimes when someone's writing something on a whiteboard they might write $\forall$ because it takes longer to write "for all," and I understand that. When I write something up here, though, I'm not in such a hurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Why I'm not allowed to say that if the derivative is zero the function is a constant?

Is that because if a function is constant then the derivative is zero, and not vice versa?"

Because this may be false if your domain is not an interval.  Consider the function
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & x < 0 \\ 2, & x > 0. \end{cases}
$$
This function has $f'(x)=0$ where it is differentiable, but it is not a constant.

Notice that in your argument you **are** on an interval, so the assumption that the derivative exists everywhere and is zero is enough to conclude that $f$ is constant.

Comment: Yeah but s/he specified [a,b] as the interval and it is true that if f'(x)=0 for all x in [a,b] then f is a constant function on [a,b].

Comment: I'm explaining why the "vice versa" might be false.

Comment: @Randall is the vice versa point the main reason of this question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The derivative of a constant function is zero says:

IF $f$ is a constant function, THEN the derivative of $f$ is $0$

It is important to understand that in general, we cannot assume the converse (the "vice versa") of a statement that says "If this, then that."

Simple example: "If $x = -3$, then $x^2 = 9$" is true.

The converse: "If $x^2 = 9$, then $x = -3$" is not true. ($x$ could be $3$.)

Proving that the derivative of a constant function is $0$ does not prove that a function with $0$ derivative is constant.  It is true, but one proof does not prove both directions After proving both, we may draw either conclusion from either condition.

Comment: I think you mean $x^2$ in the converse, thanks for the answer!